# Pass the Parameter value to the controller from the jquery datatable ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have a controller named as SendAjaxParameter in which I am assigning the values to the Employee class(those are just some static values). like this :

```
public ActionResult GetParameter(string name)
        {
            List<Employee> Employee_Details = new List<Employee>();
            string valueofname = name;
            Employee emp = new Employee
            {
                Name = "John",
                Surname = "Doe"
            };
            Employee emp1 = new Employee
            {
                Name = "Mary",
                Surname = "Addinson"
            };

            Employee_Details.Add(emp);
            Employee_Details.Add(emp1);
            return Json(new { data = Employee_Details, Message = "Hello all" }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
```

I want to pass the parameter from the ajax of the jquery datatable. which is a variable value.
like this :

```
<script src="~/Scripts/datatable/DataTables-1.10.20/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
        <script src="~/Scripts/datatable/DataTables-1.10.20/js/dataTables.jqueryui.min.js"></script>
        <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            var nameValue = "TestValue";
            $("#mytable").DataTable({
                "ajax": {
                    "type": "POST",
                    "url": "/SendAjaxParameter/GetParameter",
                    "data": { name: nameValue },
                    "contentType": "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    "dataType": "json"
                },
                "columns": [
                    { "data": "Name" },
                    { "data": "Surname" }
                ]
            });
        });
    </script>
```

How can I do this ? I want to use this value for the further processing. Like above code I tried but it is giving me error Please Help!
the error like :
**Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 ()**
and on view The alert box is like :
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Add `data` value as **JSON** not as `string` in `.ajax` call

```
data: {name: nameValue},
```

(or)

Could you try it as a `function` as [docs says](https://datatables.net/reference/option/ajax.data) in examples similar to below

```
$('#mytable').dataTable({
  "ajax": {
    "url": "/SendAjaxParameter/GetParameter",
    "contentType": "application/json",
    "type": "POST",
    "data": function (data) {
      return JSON.stringify(data);
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: I attached the image and changed the code as you recommended

Comment: Updated my answer. And could you please check what are you expecting at server side based on the request data in `Network` tab.

Comment: But we are not passing the value of nameValue to the function...i'm confused can you please explain it to me ?

Comment: Getting null value in the controller

Comment: 500 is internal server error. You need to check what is the `data format` you require by your server. https://datatables.net/manual/tech-notes/7 clearly says error response is from your server

Comment: Values are assigned to the table but the parameter value of the controller is a null value

Comment: Could you please confirm why the url is saying `SendAjaxParameter/GetParameter` and the `type` of request is **POST**?

Comment: Beacuse, I want to hide those values which are going to pass to the controller so I used Ajax request as post

Comment: Could you please confirm this one thing... Are you trying to read the data from server and display that data in UI screen?

Comment: What should I confirm ?

Comment: Updated my comment.

Comment: Okay I'll explain the scenario, I have a dropdown in my ui, user selects one value from the drop-down and according to that I request data to the controller and I want to  assign that data to the DataTable. So, I made separate project in which I am trying to pass static value from the ajax of DataTable

Comment: Can you please try printing data as below `function (data) { console.log("==>", data); return JSON.stringify(data); }`. And check how the data is displaying in `console`.

Comment: It is displaying some kind of object like structure

Comment: Is it the same what you need? If not you can extract data from in based in your requirement (request data to be sent to Server/Controller).

Comment: Okay I'll try...and let you know